# How can I make this work with every delimiter in C++?

Tags: c++, delimiter, arrays

I just wrote a program that tokenizes a `char` array using pointers. The program only needed to work with a space as the delimiter character. I just turned it in and got full credit, but after turning it in, I realized that this program worked *only* if the delimiter character was a space.

My question is, how could I make this program work with an arbitrary delimiter character?

The function I've shown you below returns a pointer to the next word in the char array. This is what I believe I need to change for it to work with any delimiter character.

Thanks!

Code:

```
char* StringTokenizer::Next(void) {
    pNextWord = pStart;

    if (*pStart == '\0') { return NULL; }

    while (*pStart != delim) {
        pStart++;
    }

    if (*pStart == '\0') { return NULL; }

    *pStart = '\0';
    pStart++;

    return pNextWord;
}
```

The printing loop in `main()`:

```
while ((nextWord = tk.Next()) != NULL) {
    cout << nextWord << endl;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219351/access-violation-with-pointers-c for the related/base question + answers, e.g. correcting `while (*pStart != delim)` to check for '\0'.

Comment: I still fail to understand while we have `const char*` and `c++` mixed up... will people ever realize that c-strings are the shortest road to failure ?

Comment: @Matthieu: Alex is a student learning C++. In this case, it is appropriate to learn about c-strings, arrays, etc. as basic building blocks to more-advanced containers/algorithms (e.g. STL, Boost, etc.). This helps one appreciate the more-advanced containers/algorithms, understand them (e.g., intuition about the choice between vector, list, set, etc.), and eventually how to build new & better ones. Of course, I hope his professor eventually shows him some of the better alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way is to change your

```
while (*pStart != delim)
```

to something like

```
while (*pStart != ' ' && *pStart != '\n' && *pStart != '\t')
```

Or, you could make delim a string, and create a function that checks if a char is in the string:

```
bool isDelim(char c, const char *delim) {
   while (*delim) {
      if (*delim == c)
         return true;
      delim++;
   }
   return false;
}

while ( !isDelim(*pStart, " \n\t") )
```

Or, perhaps the best solution is to use one of the prebuilt functions for doing all this, such as [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/).

Comment: Using a prebuilt function is good advice -- but strtok really isn't. It has a lousy interface so code that uses it correctly is messy, it modifies the string it's passed, and it requires something like a thread-local variable (or two) to work correctly in a multithreaded environment. Nearly the *only* standard library function that's worse is `gets()`.

Comment: @bramp: it sounds like the homework assignment is to actually implement a version of strtok (for better or worse). Also, remember to add the `*pStart != '\0'` check to the main while loop.

Comment: @Jason Yep, that was basically the assignment. Like I said, turned it in and got full credit, but I'm trying to make it work with all delimiter characters, not just spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the line

```
while (*pStart != delim)
```

as follows:

```
while (*pStart != '\0' && strchr(" \t\n", *pStart) == NULL)
```

The standard `strchr` function (declared in the `string.h` header)
looks for a character (given in the second argument) in a C-string
(given in the first argument) and returns a pointer to the position
where that character occurs for the first time. Hence, the expression
`strchr(" \t\n", *pStart) == NULL` is true if the current character
(`*pStart`) cannot be not found in string `" \t\n"` and, therefore,
is not a delimiter. (Modify the delimiter string to adapt it to your
needs, of course.)

This approach provides a short and simple way to test whether a given
character belongs to a (small) set of characters of interest. And it
uses a standard function.

By the way, you can do this using not only a C-string, but with
a `std::string`, too. All you need is to declare a `const std::string`
with `" \t\n"`-like value and then replace the call to the `strchr`
function with the `find` method of the declared delimiter string.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...this doesn't look quite right:

```
if (*pStart = '\0')
```

The condition can never be true. I'm guessing you intended `==` instead of `=`? You also have a bit of a problem here:

```
while (*pStart != delim)
```

If the last word in the string isn't followed by a delimiter, this is going to run off the end of the string, which will cause serious problems.

Edit: Unless you really need to do this on your own, consider using a stringstream for the job. It already has all the right mechanism in place and quite heavily tested. It does add overhead, but it's quite acceptable in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Not compiled. but I'd do something like this.

```
 //const int N = someGoodValue;
char delimList[N] = {' ',',','.',';', '|', '!', '$', '\n'};//all delims here.

char* StringTokenizer::Next(void)
{
    if (*pStart == '\0') { return NULL; }

    pNextWord = pStart;

    while (1){  
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++){
            if (*pStart == delimList[x]){ //this is it.
                *pStart = '\0';
                pStart++;
                return pNextWord;
            }

        }
        if ('\0' == *pStart){ //last word.. maybe.
                return pNextWord;   
        }
        pStart++;
    }
}

// (!compiled).
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that we want to stick to C instead of C++. Functions `strspn` and `strcspn` are good for tokenizing by a set a delimiters. You can use strspn to find where the next separator begins (i.e. where the current token ends) and then using strcspn to find where the separator ends (i.e. where the next token begins). Loop until you reach the end.

Comment: What I described is pretty much equivalent to what strtok does. Using those two functions is not really harder than using strtok and they avoid the nasty problems that there are with strtok. However, what you are required to do in the exercise might slightly differ from that because delimiters are not getting combined.